# How to deploy a GitHub repository page inside another website directory

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

This is hard to explain but here is what I want:

Suppose I created a GitHub Pages site by creating a repository of the same name, and now my main page is hosted on *example.github.io*.
Now, I want a directory called *games* in my site. It may not have any HTML structure.

Before that, I created a new repository called *local*, and added an *index.html* file to it. My page is now hosted on *example.github.io/local*

However, I want it to be hosted inside the *games* directory, like *example.github.io/games/local*

I know that one can create folders inside repositories, and it will be deployed like that. But that is hard to manage when you have several webpages like that, and also ultimately, it can raise storage issues for one repository too. Also, it references the file in the URL with *.html* extension.

Is there any way I can declare the *games* directory and also deploy the repository page there?

I couldn't really find any solutions to this, so couldn't try much, and also, I am fairly new to GitHub.